# Android: Button Click || New Activity? || NEED Assistance

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I am looking to essentially make program that will do the following and am having trouble figuring out buttons and transitioning activities with them.  No input other than button presses needed.

1-Textview containing a question.
2-Button to display the answer to question.
3-Textview to put to answer provided by button click.
4-Button to display next activity formatted the same way (5 times repeated)
5-Also need buttons to end the application all together.

I know this is probably one of the lowest level questions, but I cannot find how to get the buttons to do anything (Part 2,4,and 5 of the list above)

I assume it has something to do with initially setting the answer to the question invisible until button is pressed then revealing it.

Please help me with this elementary level question! :(

Below is my layout file, and the main java file is pretty stingy for this project so it will not be attached in its current state as it is mostly a layout issue I am trying to resolve.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Textview android:id="@+id/Questions"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:text="@string/Q1"   />

<Button android:id="@+id/QButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_question" 
android:onClick="buttonQuestion" />

<Button android:id="@+id/AButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="buttonAnswer"/>

<Textview android:id="@+id/Answers"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
android:onClick="sendMessage" />

<Button android:id="@+id/QuitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_quit" 
    android:onClick="buttonQuit"/>
```

Comment: i am not getting what u want to do .if u can make it more clear i can help you

Comment: i think you should draw a raw picture in paint and post here to show which type of view you required...

Answer (score 0):

You can set text of your `textview` using `findViewById` (to find specific `textview`) and `setText()` (to set your answer). Refer to these links: [findViewByID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) and [setText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Initially your `textView` text referring to answer could be set to something like empty string `setText("");`

```
Button answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AButton);
    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Answers);
            answerText.setText("Your answer");
        }
    });
```

Also you can keep your Q&A in string arrays (if you already have couple questions and answers) and just iterate trough arrays on button click (your next question button. I think it's `QButton` in your layout) without the need for new activity.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create methods for each button in the java class where you are using this layout like so.

```
public void buttonQuestion(View v){
        TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Answers);
        answerText.setText("Your answer");
    }

public void buttonAnswer(View v){
            //do something
        }

public void sendMessage(View v){
            //do something
        }

public void buttonQuit(View v){
            finish();
        }
```